# RasPi Remote GPIO pizero Problems

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to controll motors and a servos connected to a Raspberry Pi Zero 2w from a windows machine via python. I dont have much expierience with RasPi but I managed to get an Led to blink via remote GPIO, changed the code a little bit so my H-Bridge turned the motor:

```
from gpiozero import LED
from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory
from time import sleep

factory = PiGPIOFactory(host='') #IP is cut out for publishing
led1 = LED(17, pin_factory=factory)
led2 = LED(27, pin_factory=factory)

def forward():
    led2.off()
    led1.on()

def backward():
    led1.off()
    led2.on()

def stop():
    led1.off()
    led2.off()

    
while True:
    forward()
    sleep(1)
    stop()
    sleep(1)
    backward()
    sleep(1)
```

This works without problems. Then I found out gpiozero offers a Motor class. I tryed this:

```
from gpiozero import Motor
from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory
from time import sleep

factory = PiGPIOFactory(host='') #IP is cut out for publishing

motor1 = Motor(17, 27, pin_factory=factory)
    
while True:
    motor1.forward()
    sleep(3)
    motor1.stop()
    sleep(1)
    motor1.backward()
    sleep(1)
```

This doesn`t work. Following is the output:

```
C:\Users\gerre\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\gpiozero\devices.py:288: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from rpigpio: No module named 'RPi'
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\gerre\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\gpiozero\devices.py:288: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from lgpio: No module named 'lgpio'
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\gerre\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\gpiozero\devices.py:288: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from rpio: No module named 'RPIO'  warnings.warn(
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Can't connect to pigpio at localhost(8888)

Did you start the pigpio daemon? E.g. sudo pigpiod

Did you specify the correct Pi host/port in the environment
variables PIGPIO_ADDR/PIGPIO_PORT?
E.g. export PIGPIO_ADDR=soft, export PIGPIO_PORT=8888

Did you specify the correct Pi host/port in the
pigpio.pi() function? E.g. pigpio.pi('soft', 8888)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
C:\Users\gerre\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\gpiozero\devices.py:288: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from pigpio: failed to connect to localhost:8888
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\gerre\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\gpiozero\devices.py:288: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from native: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/cpuinfo'
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[cut out]\RemoteMotor.py", line 7, in <module>
    motor1 = Motor(17, 27, pin_factory=factory)
  File "C:\Users\gerre\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\gpiozero\devices.py", line 108, in __call__
    self = super(GPIOMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gerre\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\gpiozero\output_devices.py", line 1223, in __init__
    super(Motor, self).__init__(_order=devices.keys(), **devices)
  File "C:\Users\gerre\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\gpiozero\mixins.py", line 85, in __init__
    super(SourceMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gerre\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\gpiozero\devices.py", line 432, in __init__
    super(CompositeDevice, self).__init__(pin_factory=pin_factory)
  File "C:\Users\gerre\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\gpiozero\devices.py", line 250, in __init__
    Device.pin_factory = Device._default_pin_factory()
  File "C:\Users\gerre\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\gpiozero\devices.py", line 291, in _default_pin_factory
    raise BadPinFactory('Unable to load any default pin factory!')
gpiozero.exc.BadPinFactory: Unable to load any default pin factory!
```

What am I missing? I dont see why using LED works and Motor doesn´t.

Edit: Servo works fine, too. Only Motor has issues.

Comment: Based on "Can't connect to pigpio at localhost(8888)" you're still trying to connect to a pigpio server on the Windows machine. Did you read the error message and try to do the things it suggests?

Comment: Ofc. I have read the error message. But I dont understand it and again the first code works without problems. So i dont see why it shoudn´t connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem on github. For anyone wondering the gpiozero lib was missing a parameter. In the output_devices.py the class Motor __init __ function it has to say:
`super(Motor, self).__init__(_order=devices.keys(), pin_factory=pin_factory, **devices)`
instead of
`super(Motor, self).__init__(_order=devices.keys(), **devices)`
Hopefully this is fixed soon.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).